# How to get server domain name at runtime?

Tags: dns, wix, windows-installer

I have a WIX file (*.wxs) in which we are using %USERDOMAIN environment variable to retrieve the domain of the logged in user. For eg., it gives DOMAINA for a user logged in as DOMAINA\user1.
This extracted domain name is then used to prefix other Security Groups that are used to ACL web resources.

It was working fine until now. But now, due to security restrictions, the logged in user is not from the same domain the server and applications run. The user is logged in from a Management domain, say DOMAINM. Now, %USERDOMAIN does not help as the resources are ACLed with incorrect SGs, like DOMAINM\SG1, etc, which don't exist.

What are my options to retrieve the domain of the server so that it can be used in the WIX file for generating MSI for deployment?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a registry value that provides this:

```
<Property Id="TCPIPDOMAIN" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="tcpipDomain" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" Name="Domain" Win64="no" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
```

There is another very important scenario where %USERDOMAIN and %USERDNSDOMAIN don't work.  Pushing an MSI out through a tool that runs as SYSTEM (such as SCCM).  The SYSTEM profile doesn't initialize these environment variables.  This is why I use the registry search technique.

Comment: Thank you...appreciate your response. Now, I need to extract short domain name only, from this string.

Comment: I wish I understood what you are doing with this.  I might be able to provide better help.

Comment: We are using WIX tools to build MSI. In the .wxs file used for building the MSI, it checks the %USERDOMAIN and then uses it to build the full security group to ACL the resources. Like PRODUCTION\SG1 for Production and INTEGRATION\SG1 for Integration environment. The %USERDOMAIN is fetched runtime based on the environment/domain. It works fine if the user who is deploying has the account in the same domain as service group. But in our case, the user accounts changed to MGMT domain, but application security groups still in PRODUCTION and INTEGRATION domains. Hence cannot depend on %USERDOMAIN.